# Sparse from big matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, matrix, bigdata, sparse-matrix

I have a graph *G(L,N)* where *L* is a set of links and *N* a set of nodes. I want to work with this graph in MATLAB using pretty much ready code that requires Sparse and Adjacency matrices.

The problem is that my graph is quite big (~71000 nodes, ~179000 links) producing a rather big adjacency matrix ~(71000x71000). In order to read this data I use a `uint32` data format that I think fits my data. However I have no idea how to convert the adjacency to sparse as the `sparse(double(Adjacency))` does not work (obviously due to memory errors). I am trying to produce the sparse piecewise as follows:

```
numberof10000 = ceil(size(Adjacency,1)/10000);
for i=1:numberof10000
    for j = 1:numberof10000
        if i ~= numberof10000
            if j~= numberof10000
                networkSparseOnes   = sparse(double(Adjacency((i-1)*10000+1:(i)*10000+1,...
                    (j-1)*10000+1:(j)*10000+1)));
            else
                networkSparseOnes   = sparse(double(Adjacency((i-1)*10000+1:...
                    (i)*10000+1,(j-1)*10000+1:end)));
            end
        else
            if j~= numberof10000
                networkSparseOnes   = sparse(double(Adjacency((i-1)*10000+1:end,...
                    (j-1)*10000+1:(j)*10000+1)));
            else
                networkSparseOnes   = sparse(double(Adjacency((i-1)*10000+1:...
                    (i)*10000+1,(j-1)*10000+1:end)));
            end
        end        
        totalSparse = [totalSparse;networkSparseOnes];
    end
end
```

To be honest I would like to hear some opinions on my thoughts and suggestions for improvement or any other way, if any.

Comment: is `Adjacency` a non-sparse matrix of size 71000x71000?

Comment: yes it is! It is a uint32 matrix

Comment: this is already 18.78 gigabytes then, right? is the matrix content sparse or dense? how do you populate the `Adjancency` matrix? is this all stored in a file?

Comment: Yes it is rather big. It is not stored in a file, it is not sparse (or dense). I populate it from links that I have:

for i=1:size(AllLinks,1)
        or      = find(AllNodes(:,1)==AllLinks(i,2));
        dest    = find(AllNodes(:,1)==AllLinks(i,3));
        Adjacency(or,dest) = 1;
        AdjacencyCost(or,dest) = AllLinks(i,4);
    end

Comment: but couldn't you populate a sparse matrix exactly like this? generate a zero sparse matrix first and then fill it with the data

Comment: Oh my god you are right. I guess I was thinking that you cannot fill directly a sparse matrix and that you can only do it based on an adjacency. I should probably delete this question.